# Ansible variables file as map does not consider parameterized values

Tags: amazon-web-services, variables, ansible

I use ansible for managing several AWS resources, such as DMS.
I want to control via a variables map. The dmsTask which is either "resume-processing" or "stopping" is mapped to the variable and the commands are passed to the task accordingly:

```
/vars/dms.yml

    my_dms_tasks:
      resumeProcessing:
        mainCommand: |
                    aws dms start-replication-task 
                    --replication-task-arn "{{item.RepTaskArn}}"
                    --start-replication-task-type resume-processing
        description: Resume processing
        waitCommand: aws dms wait replication-task-running --filters '[{"Name":"replication-task-arn","Values":{{replicationTaskArns}}}]'
      stopping:
        mainCommand: |
                  aws dms stop-replication-task 
                  --replication-task-arn "{{item.RepTaskArn}}"
        description: Stopping
        waitCommand: aws dms wait replication-task-stopped --filters '[{"Name":"replication-task-arn","Values":{{replicationTaskArns}}}]
```

This is my root playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    endpointIdentifiers: "{{endpointIdentifiers}}"
    dmsTask: "{{dmsTask}}"

  tasks:

    - name: Include vars
      include_vars: dms.yml
      register: my_dms_tasks

    - debug:
        var: dms_tasks


##### Get the relevant endpoints for identifying the corresponding dms tasks #####

##### Transform the result of 'get endpoint arn' into a Json object #####

##### Get relevant dms tasks via the aws cli #####
    - import_tasks: tasks/task_get_dms.yml

##### Transfom the result of 'get dms tasks' into a Json object #####
    - set_fact:
        replicationTaskArnsJson: "{{replicationTaskArns.results[0].stdout | from_json}}"

##### Based on the passed dmsTask act accordingly #####
    - import_tasks: tasks/task_modify_dms.yml
```

The task playbook looks like this:

```
tasks/task_modify_dms.yml
- name: Manage DMS tasks
      block:
      - name: "Resume processing DMS tasks"
        command: "{{my_dms_tasks[dmsTask].mainCommand}}"
        loop: "{{replicationTaskArnsJson.RepTasks}}"
        register: tasksResult

      - name: "Get the 'replication-task-arns' as list"
        set_fact: 
          replicationTaskArns: "{{tasksResult | json_query('results[*].item.RepTaskArn') | to_json}}"

      - name : "Show replicationTaskArns as Json"
        debug:
          var: replicationTaskArns

      # Wait for the tasks to be finished, then proceed
      - name: "Wait until DMS tasks have finished"
        command: "{{my_dms_task[dmsTask].waitCommand"
      rescue:
        - debug:
            msg: "Nothing to change"
```

The error is:

```
failed: [localhost] (item={u'Status': u'stopped', u'RepTaskIdentifier': u'guidewire-qa-pc01-gsec-ongoing', u'RepTaskArn': u'arn:aws:dms:eu-central-1:118628429710:task:MCH3GI2YVW77Y7M5N5V5KB5TSU'}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "cmd": ["aws", "dms", "stop-replication-task", "--replication-task-arn", "{{item.RepTaskArn}}"]...
```

Why is "{{item.RepTaskArn}}" not being resolved?

Comment: I think I experienced a similar issue recently with such a complex var setup. Can you try to replace `command: "{{my_dms_tasks[dmsTask].mainCommand}}"` with `command: "{{ (lookup('dict', my_dms_task) | items2dict)[dmsTask].mainCommand }}"` and see if it fixes you issue ? I know it looks totally stupid but the idea is to force reinterpretation of the unresolved vars. I have no clue yet in which situations this happens exactly (except in somewhat edge cases like your example and the one I was facing...)

Comment: I found the solution.
I had to subsitute "import_tasks" with "include_tasks"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to substitute **"import_tasks"** with **"include_tasks"**.